# Determining ACL change in Alfresco

Tags: permissions, alfresco, acl

Hello I need to determine if ACL has changed for any node in Alfresco. I was trying to check if some new records arrived in alf_acl_change_set but there is no ifnormation about that.
Please help me.

Comment: Snapshot the permissions, then compare later? Or otherwise what about wrapping the Authority Service with your own code that logs?